# Ansible Host Variable Issues

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have a issue when i am trying to have a  conditional statement based on the variable set in my inventory file. Below is the details. My inventory file looks like this.

```
[webserver]
server1
server2

[appserver]
server1

[webserver:vars]
TYPE=w

[appserver:vars]
TYPE=a
```

Now when i am trying to add a condition in my task like

```
name: abc
  shell: run this task
when: TYPE == "w"

name: cde
  shell: run this task
when: TYPE == "a"
```

Now when i run the Play 1 it picks up the first variable and stores it but when it  tries to run the task second time (Play2) its still have the same variable and fails. I have two plays 1 for web and other for app. Please let me know what may be the issue.

Comment: Yes, that’s how it is expected to work. Variables are assigned to hosts, not groups. Rethink your variable usage. Use separate ones (like a switch on/off) for each function. *For sure this is a duplicate, but it will take time to locate.*

Answer (score 0):

You can't define the same variable twice in an inventory file, even if it belongs to another group.
After the parsing of your inventory file the only "TYPE" known to Ansible will be the last one defined in your inventory file. In your case that would be one within appserver. 
If you switch the order of your variables you will face the exact opposite behavior I guess.

In my opinion you should change the way to determine which tasks to run.

Little example:

```
- name: some task for webservers
  shell: run this webserver task
  when: run_webserver_task

- name: some task for appservers
  shell: run this appserver task
  when: run_appserver_task
```

Please see this link as evidence for my bold statement:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6538

OR

You could try to design your inventory file the yamlish way instead of using an ini file. Please see:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html